# Build output file "buildConfig.java" has null boolean error in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I fork Lawnchair-V1 to my GitHub repo opened via "get if from version control" to my android studio. After I got some error so I changed Kotilin version and  `kotlin-stdlib-jre7` to `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` which solved the error `Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KotlinSourceSetProviderImplKt`

After that, when I run the application I got 2 error showing

```
public static final boolean TRAVIS = null;

public static final boolean TAGGED_BUILD = null;
```

In the BuildConfig.java generated file
I know there is something wrong with Build.gradle(:app)
But I can't find the error
if you can please help me
https://gist.github.com/Sreejithns2002/f22b6ee3aef3568bd1af45502af1464b

Comment: `buildConfigField "boolean", "TRAVIS", isTravis`. Did you check how `isTravis` is initialized?

Comment: I am new to android studio and I am really struggling. I think It is initiated in 10 and 11th line of code https://gist.github.com/Sreejithns2002/f22b6ee3aef3568bd1af45502af1464b

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti okay then. How to initialise it? Please reply.